# Can men daven at home to avoid the bad smell of people at shul?

Tags: tefilla, synagogue, personal-hygiene

Can men daven at home to avoid the bad smell of people at shul? It can be very irritating to someone. can somebody daven at home so that they can have proper kavannah during davening by avoiding those bad smells coming from people in shul sweating in their clothes or from them wearing uncleaned clothes?

Comment: This sounds like the sort of weighing of values that is dependent on the particulars of the situation. It doesn't sound like something that can be addressed in the general case.

Comment: @Isaac Mosesl I think my question will apply to everyone who has ever had to experience bad smells in shul.

Comment: Halchically, the prohibition of praying in a place that has a foul odor, I believe, applies only to *amidah* and specifically to odor caused by feces and I think garbage. Sweat and B.O. I don't believe is one of them. Despite these parameters, if being in such an environment is so intoilerable that you couldn't daven in shul, anyway, then your being there serves little purpose other than, maybe, to help form a minyan. If the minyan is there without you, you may be better off praying at home where at least you would pray in the first place.